# Best Drive Format for a 2TB Seagate External HDD, which can be supported in all OS

Tags: windows, linux, mac, external-hard-drive, filesystems

I have a 2TB Seagate GoFlex Desk External HDD. I want to format it. Which is the best disk format, which will be supported in all OS, like Windows, Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found **NTFS**, sadly, the be the "most" portable.

In most cases you'll at least be able to read ntfs without OS modifications.

For write support in Linux, you may need to install *ntfs-3g*.

For write support in OSX, you should consider installing [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) with a [NTFS driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/).

**EXT2/3 Alternatively**

You could use something like ext3 which anything calling itself a unix derivative should support quite well. You can [install this to get support in Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/). That driver will only mount the ext3 file system as an ext2, which will work, but disables file system journaling, meaning you'd have to do some scanning/fixing if you crash the file system or uncleanly mount it in some way.

OSX supports ext3 out of the box (which it should, being a unix system). But you may have problems with Finder automounting it, probably depends on the version of OSX. [Look here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=34227) for some mounting tips, if necessary.

**File Server, if you don't care about the external drive part**

If you want to use that drive to store massive amounts of data for various machines, you may want to considering running a file server for it. Some people get all whiney about incurring extra power costs, so you can consider that, though if you do it well the cost won't be a lot.

You could find a computer to toss the drive in, set it up with [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) and provide access to your drive over your network using the samba/cifs file sharing protocol - which all major OSes support very well.